# Is http-inbound gateway can be do something like preHandle and postHandle of interceptor?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-dsl

I want to put a "UUID" into MDC when the service accept a http request.
Because it's convenience for log search.

I was inherited HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway and found the handleRequest() was final so that I can't overwrite it .

So is there a way to do something when accept a request(MDC.put()) and write response(MDC.remove()) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not an `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` responsibility to manipulate a request that way.

I think you need to take a look into a *Web Filter* registration: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/

As a point of idea you can borrow an existing `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter`:

```
 * Base class for {@code Filter}s that perform logging operations before and after a request
 * is processed.
 *
 * <p>Subclasses should override the {@code beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest, String)} and
 * {@code afterRequest(HttpServletRequest, String)} methods to perform the actual logging
 * around the request.
```